# How to remove 'Edit' link from shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

We are trying to remove the "edit" link from the shopping cart for our install.   From the searching we have done so far, we have been directed to edit the default.phtml file for our theme.

We have done this however the edit button remains.

We are using Magento CE 1.9.3.1

The part we have commented out/deleted is

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Edit item parameters')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
```

Does anyone know a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

The items in the cart are rendered by different templates depending on the product type.
So you need to edit multiple templates in order to remove that completely.

- template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
- template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

But don't remove just the `<a>` tag. Remove the `<td>` also that wraps the `<a>`.

And you need to remove the column header for this column from `template/checkout/cart.phtml`
Remove `<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"></th>` from above `<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>`.
and `<col width="1" />` from above `<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>`.

You might also want to remove it from the sidebar cart block

- template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml